# Forge: Occasional 403 when trying to GetPublishJob

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

We are occasionally seeing an issue with some projects where, when we try to do a GetPublishJob on a BIM360 model, we get back a 403 error, like this:

```
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"id":"ad23cbc6-dc82-4dfd-83f9-6acd14bac6d2","status":"403","code":"C4R","detail":"Failed to get publish model job"}]}
```

In the docs, it says it could be whitelisting or permissions. We know our app is whitelisted, because we would not have made it this far if it wasn't. We're using 3-legged OAuth, and we believe that the user is able to manually perform the Publish. Can you tell us what specific other permissions might need to be investigated?

Answer (score 0):

I am not typing answer, while I want to check some information with you:

if what you are using is this endpoint, it is public, so it does not need whitelisted. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/GetPublishModelJob/ .

Since you are using 3 legged token, I doubt it may due to the expired token, while normally it should be 401 error.

With the same token, can your code perform Publish Model?
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/PublishModel/

was this workflow working well in the past? or just failed recently?

To use this endpoint, the logged user (for 3 legged token) should have access with the folder.

Comment: Hello - this works for us with many customers. Just some odd cases where it does not seem to work (and the 403 error doesn't really make sense).  With regards to running the PublishModel command, we are using the GetPublishModelJob to determine if we even need to run the PublishModel command. We believe that the user has full access to the folder.

Comment: we may have to check remotely. Could you email us at  forge.help@autodesk.com with the contact information, your time zone and the available time slots?  Thank you.

Comment: I am having the same issue, are there any updates on this question?